# Problema con archivo csv con numero con delimitador decimal coma

Tags: c#, csv, archivo

Estoy haciendo un método en c# que me permita procesar ciertos archivos csv con la siguiente característica:

```
SampleNumber,Date,Time,D1,D2,D3
2000,05/14/2020,00:00:35.111418,-0,0108274578293113,0,0232095051726457,1,00140963195599
2001,05/14/2020,00:00:35.111918,-0,0107080575461965,0,0232479792659256,1,00137780739509
.
.
.
```

Lo que hacia con otros formatos era leer linea por linea, almacenar en un string y luego dividir la cadena con split usando el separador, pero en este caso particular no puedo ya que los números tienen su parte decimal separada de la entera divida con coma, lo intente hacer usando la librería TinyCsvParser pero tampoco obtuve el resultado esperado, de que forma podría separar las columnas de forma que ignore la coma en los datos numéricos?

Comment: siempre llegan un numero de un solo digito por delante?

Comment: Si, los valores se mueven entre -1 y 1

Comment: porque no cambiar el caracter, en mi caso use el caracter "|" es muy dificil que alguna palabra tenga ese caracter, si no mal recuerdo se llama pipe y su combinación de alt+124, podrias sustituir las cosas por esté